# AspxGridView and ASPxSummaryItem display not complete[DEVEXPRESS]

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

How can I show the complete totalizer(ASPxSummaryItem)in a ASPxGridView, , without having to drag the entire column?
I've tried changing the propierty "ShowInColumn", but nothing happens.
I put two photos attached showing the problem.

Thank's[image: You may notice that the totalizer description is nescessário expand the column to display everything.]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q335551) "ShowInColumn" property has to work. I've tried the code below on my project and it works fine.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="_sumBudgetGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" KeyFieldName="id">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn Name="Cmd"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="budget" Caption="<%$ Resources:ProjectCostResources,UI_BudgetItem_Budget_Sum %>" Width="100px" />
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="forecast" Caption="<%$ Resources:ProjectCostResources,UI_BudgetItem_Forecast_Sum %>" Width="100px" />
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="procurement" Caption="<%$ Resources:ProjectCostResources,UI_BudgetItem_Procurement_Sum %>" Width="100px" />
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="actual" Caption="<%$ Resources:ProjectCostResources,UI_BudgetItem_Actual_Sum %>" Width="100px" VisibleIndex="4"/>
    </Columns>
    <TotalSummary>
        <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="forecast" SummaryType="Sum" ShowInColumn="Cmd" />
        <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="budget" SummaryType="Sum" ShowInColumn="Cmd"/>
        <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="procurement" SummaryType="Sum" ShowInColumn="Cmd"/>
        <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="actual" SummaryType="Sum" />
    </TotalSummary>
    <Settings ShowFooter="True" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I know, but I meant that I tried to do the totalizer occupy the space of two columns, like the "Coolspan" HTML propierty. Because the way it is now, I am required to maintain "Embarque" column expanded the most, just so the text appears.